# How do I email a user from a custom sharepoint list?

Tags: list, sharepoint-enterprise, email

I have a custom list that populates from a suggestion box on the home page from employees.

I have also displayed the created by column to show who submitted the suggestion.

Now, how can I email a paticular user if I wish to ask him/her a follow up question??

I trired the drop down on the items but it dosent have an option to email 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are an administrator you can also set an alert for any user on the item.

At my company we have also experimented with a list type that lets users confirm they have reviewed an item.  The list type I am talking about is "Circulation."  It allows you to write a title, body, permissions, and set whichever recipients you want to be able to view said circulation.  When you create an item it sends emails to all of the recipients you select.  I do not know if this is available in SharePoint Foundation, however, but since your tags include "SharePoint Enterprise" I am hoping you will be OK.

****EDIT****

After looking at your original question again, I thought about it some more and realized you could just click on the user's name.  Especially if you have Lync at your company this will give you options to email, IM or even call the person who submitted the suggestion.  Even if this is not enabled their name should take you to their profile, which should have an email address.  This, again, is probably determined by your SharePoint configuration and/or Active Directory settings.

- Matt

Answer (score 2):

I'd maybe create a manually initiated workflow with initiation parameters for subject and body.  Then the workflow would email the created by person and merge in your initiation parameters into the subject and body.

Or you could create a dataview web part to do it, https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/sharepoint-mailto-hyperlink-in-a-dvwp.aspx